# Why isn't my Markdown file being gzipped?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, gzip, markdown

I have this in my `.htaccess` file:

```
# gzip compression
<ifmodule mod_deflate.c>
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/text text/html text/plain text/xml text/css application/x-javascript application/javascript application/json
</ifmodule>
```

This makes sure that the given content types are gzipped.

**Live demo:** http://ecmazing.com/js/index.js (Open "Net" panel in browser's dev tools, and look at the response headers)

[image]

But my Markdown file is *not* being gzipped.

**Live demo:** http://ecmazing.com/data.md

[image]

As you can see the file's content type is `text/plain` which *is* in the list of content-types in my `.htaccess` file. Then, why isn't GZIP applied?

Comment: And files with the ending `.md` are associated with one of the Mime types that you have listed after `AddOutputFilterByType` …? Have you tried `AddOutputFilter deflate md` instead?

Comment: @CBroe The server is responding with `Content-Type text/plain`. Doesn't that mean yes?

Comment: @CBroe I've added `AddOutputFilter deflate md` and it works now :). Could you explain why that is?

Comment: I’d guess that your markdown files are not actively assigned the Content-type text/plain via an `AddType` directive – so the server might send that content type as a default value, but `AddOutputFilterByType` does not make that connection that connection automatically …

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I’d guess that your markdown files are not actively assigned the Content-type `text/plain` via an `AddType` directive – so the server might send that content type as a default value, but `AddOutputFilterByType` does not recognize these files as being of that content type automatically.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/mod/core.html#addoutputfilterbytype confirms that, saying:

> *“Enabling filters with AddOutputFilterByType may fail partially or completely in some cases. For example, no filters are applied if the MIME-type could not be determined and falls back to the DefaultType setting, even if the DefaultType is the same.”*

So use `AddOutputFilter deflate md` instead – or try associating `.md` with the content type explicitly, using `AddType text/plain md`.

Comment: Yup. I've ended up doing this `AddType 'text/plain; charset=UTF-8' md`. I've added the charset too, as my MD contains non-ASCII characters.